# D3 time scales being split onto two lines

Tags: d3.js

I have a time-series d3.js chart which I can't seem to get lined up properly. Initially I create the x-axis with:

```
var x_domain = d3.extent(active_data, function(d) { return d.date; })
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(x_domain)
    .range([bar_width/2, width-bar_width/2]); // stop bars going outside chart

var date_format = d3.time.format("%b %y");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("bottom")
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(8)
    .tickFormat(date_format);

// create the xAxis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
   .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

svg.selectAll(".x text") // some legacy code I had lying around
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + this.getBBox().height*3 + "," + this.getBBox().height + ")rotate(0)";
```

and then I update later on when user selects a date range. "active_data" is updated with the actual values/dates that will show from my total data before this update.

```
function update_chart(start){
    /*...update active_data and other stuff...*/

    x.domain(d3.extent(active_data, function(d){return d.date;}))
    .range([bar_width/2, width-bar_width/2]);           

    /*...*/
    var svg = d3.select("body").transition().duration(500);
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

There's a lot more going on, but those are the related bits that I'm having trouble with. I've tried everything I can think of, searched online and I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong. It produces the following sort of problem:

[d3 time scale some ticks on second line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Zhm.jpg)

You can see the dates go onto the second line. On some charts, when I update to the lowest or the maximum date, it draws it correctly, then draws all of them correctly afterwards. On another chart, it does this:

[ticks all over each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rw0i.jpg)

On this second one, I don't change the .ticks(8), so I don't know why it does that. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, and there were a couple bugs.

Then, the following was giving some dates a special x location, but not all of them:

```
// create the xAxis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
   .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
```

I changed it to:

```
    // create the xAxis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

and let the update do all the work (let D3 figure it out). The date was now in the right spot, except it was vertical instead of horizontal. I fixed that by removing this:

```
svg.selectAll(".x text") // some legacy code I had lying around
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + this.getBBox().height*3 + "," + this.getBBox().height + ")rotate(0)";
```

And it works properly!